# Limiting join to full set instead of subset

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm attempting to get a list of IDs for posts which are visible only to certain users. My current statement is this:

```
SELECT `p`.`id` 
FROM   `posts` AS `p` 
       INNER JOIN `post_visibilities` AS `pv` 
               ON `pv`.`post_id` = `p`.`id` 
WHERE  `pv`.`user_id` IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4 );
```

this somewhat works, but the `IN()` clause is acting somewhat like a subset, and I'm getting posts returned which are visible by those four users *and* other users. I need to find posts which are visible to *only* those four users.

Comment: ah one moment you want to get posts that are ONLY available to them and NOT to other users?

Comment: Juans answer just brought me to the question: do all 4 of them have to have access rights? or is it regardless which one of the 4 as long as no one else than these 4?

Comment: @Thomas You are right, question can be different on how you read it. Post need to be visible to all 4,  Or just visible to any of those 4 and no one else.

Comment: I think we covered both variants there^^ one by each of us :) lets see what the op has to say.

Answer (score 0):

You could translate it directly and use a not exists there.
Although I have to say a not exists (and thus a subquery) is always a bit slow.
Not sure if there are any faster methods.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `p`.`id` 
FROM   `posts` AS `p` 
       INNER JOIN `post_visibilities` AS `pv` 
               ON `pv`.`post_id` = `p`.`id` 
WHERE  `pv`.`user_id` IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4 )
       and not exists (select 1 from `post_visibilities` as 'excluder'
         where excluder.post_id = p.id and excluder.user_id not in (1,2,3,4));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Conditional `SUM`

- I assume `post_visibilty` only have each `ID` once for each post.
- If all 4 `ID` have `post_visibilty` for the post `SUM` will be 4
- If any one else also have `post_visibilty` `SUM` will never be 4.

.

```
SELECT `p`.`id` 
FROM   `posts` AS `p` 
INNER JOIN `post_visibilities` AS `pv` 
           ON `pv`.`post_id` = `p`.`id` 
GROUP BY `p`.`id` 
HAVING SUM (CASE 
              WHEN `pv`.`user_id` IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4 ) THEN 1
              ELSE -1
            END) = 4;
```

The other interpretation of your question also can be done with conditional `SUM`

```
HAVING 
    SUM (CASE 
           WHEN `pv`.`user_id` IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4 ) THEN 1
           ELSE 0 
         END) >= 1   -- one or more have visibilty
AND SUM (CASE 
           WHEN `pv`.`user_id` NOT IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4 ) THEN 1
           ELSE 0 
         END) = 0   -- no one else have visibilty
```